# automatic order id system check existence in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

What I am trying to achieve is I have a systematic order generating system for my website I am just not able to check if the order id already exist if yes then it should increase the number by 1. heres my code end result

for e.g

Order ID: ABCD-00001 (already exist in db then)
New Order ID: ABCD-00002 (and so on...)

```
$i=0;
$n=1;
while ($i<10000) {

$j = sprintf("%'.05d\n", $n);
$orderid= "ABCD"."-".$j;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE jobid='".$orderid."'") or die (mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    $i++; $n++;


                } else { $jobid = $orderid; 
                            break; }
```

Comment: instead of ABCD as they primary key, you know you can use a number and have it autoincrement?

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).